# iphone app submission with other developers binary

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, store

I am making an app that needs to be released by the client.

Am I able to build and sign the final binary with my distribution certificate and send it to the client to upload?

Or will I have to send them the source to compile with there own certificate?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have them send you their certificate. They'll need to export it from Keychain Access, and send you the .p12 file. Then you can import that into your keychain, and build against their distribution mobileprovision file.

Otherwise, there's no way let them distribute your binary.

Comment: That is not correct. You can send them the unsigned binary and they can sign it using their cert using the the codesign_allocate and code_sign commandline tools.

Comment: ah, I didn't think those were supported methods for app submission to the App Store. Thanks!

Comment: Supported is sort of a nebulous thing here. Apple just basically posts a tutorial on how to sign an app, not the actual signing requirements or technical details. Having said that, it is indistinguishable from what Xcode does (since at the end of the day Xcode builds and unsigned binary then uses those tools to sign it).